# Windows Audio / WaveInAddBuffer() blocks

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, audio, waveform

My application records audio samples from a microphone connected to my PC. So I chose the Windows `WaveInXXX` API to do the job.

After reading the documentation I decided to avoid using the callback mechanism with `WaveInProc` to save me the hassle synchronizing the threads. The whole application is pretty big and I thought this would make debugging simpler. When the application requests a block of samples, I just iterate over my buffer queue, take one out, copy the data, unprepare it, prepare it and add it back to the buffer queue. Basic program structure looks like this, I hope it makes the basic program flow clear:

```
WaveInOpen()
WaveInStart()
FunctionAddingPreparedBuffersToTheQueue()
while(someConditionThatEventuallyBecomesFalse)
    if(NextBufferInQueueIsMarkedDone)
        GetDataFromBuffer()
        UnpreparePrepareHeaderAndAddBuffer()
    else
        WaitForAShortTime()
WaveInStop()
WaveInClose()
```

Now the problem appears: After some time (and I am unable to reproduce the exact condition), `WaveInAddBuffer()` causes a deadlock although it's in the same thread as all the rest. The header for the buffer that shall be added when the deadlock happens is prepared and `dwFlags == WHDR_PREPARED == 2`.

Any ideas what could cause this deadlock?

Comment: Even though you don't know the cause of the problem yet, try to post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org), to illustrate the problem you are facing.

Comment: So what callback mechanism you are using, `CALLBACK_NULL`? At deadlock time you can break in and catch frozen thread call stacks - this is what is going to be helpful. My guess is the problem is around `NextBufferInQueueIsMarkedDone` and you are checking buffer flags accessing them immediately (checking for `WHDR_DONE`). If so, you should not be doing this, and you should obtain notification on buffer availability through callback mechanism of your preference.

Comment: @RomanR. I followed your advice, used `CALLBACK_FUNCTION` instead of `CALLBACK_NULL` and now the deadlocks are gone, so thanks for that! Unfortunately, I still can't say what the initial problem was which is a bit unsatisfying. Why do you think is checking the buffer flags like I did previously a problem?

Comment: API reads/writes the flags on worker threads. Accessing them directly you are unable to synchronize access with the API, so you have to rely on API's return of the buffers to you and not on buffer flags you can read directly.

Answer (score 2):

I have not seen such a problem, but a guess might be something like fragmentation related to all the unprepare/prepare cycles. They are not necessary. You can do the prepare once for each buffer and then unprepare when finished recording. (Prepare locks the buffer into physical memory.)